# Augment java collection to get Interval Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, interval-tree

I was going through the [Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) chapter 14 (augmented data structures), in which he was talking about Interval Trees. Below is what he mentioned about the design approach behind interval tree.

> **Step 1: Underlying data structure**
>
> We choose a red-black tree in which each node *x* contains an interval *x:int* and the key of *x* is the low endpoint, *x.int.low*, of the interval. Thus, an inorder tree walk of the data structure lists the intervals in sorted order by low endpoint.

This can be done by declaring a node having *min* and *max*. The *comparableTo* function should compare only *x.int.low*.

> **Step 2: Additional information**
>
> In addition to the intervals themselves, each node *x* contains a value *x.max*, which is the maximum value of any interval endpoint stored in the sub-tree rooted at *x*.
>
> **Step 3: Maintaining the information**
>
> We must verify that insertion and deletion take *O(lg n)* time on an interval tree of n nodes. We can determine *x.max* given interval *x.int* and the *max* values of node *x*’s children:
>
> *x:max = max(x.int.high; x.left.max; x.right.max)*
>
> **Step 4: Developing new operations**
>
> The only new operation we need is `INTERVAL-SEARCH`(*T*,*i*), which finds a node in tree *T* whose interval overlaps interval *i*. If there is no interval that overlaps *i* in the tree, the procedure returns a pointer to the sentinel *T:nil*.

I can implement this by *AVL tree* but out of curiosity want to know whether we can augment existing libraries in java like *TreeSet* or other *collection entity* to fit to above design. If so, can you please help in a sample code or example?

Comment: In particular, I think the reason you can't do this is that you can't hook into tree rotation events to update the `max` value.

Comment: @ErikP. thanks. I have implemented by myself and below i have put. Comment on the same if you have any.

Comment: An AVL based Java implementation, which is maintained, is also available here https://github.com/Breinify/brein-time-utilities/#intervaltree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interval tree implementation with [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

```
public class IntervalTreeAVL<T>{
    private static class TreeNode<T>{
        private T low;
        private T high;
        private TreeNode<T> left;
        private TreeNode<T> right;
        private T max;
        private int height;
        private TreeNode(T l, T h){
            this.low=l;
            this.high=h;
            this.max=high;
            this.height=1;
        }
    }
    private TreeNode<T> root;
    public void insert(T l, T h){
        root=insert(root, l, h);
    }
    private TreeNode<T> insert(TreeNode<T> node, T l, T h){
        if(node==null){
            return new TreeNode<T>(l, h);
        }
        else{
            int k=((Comparable)node.low).compareTo(l);
            if(k>0){
                node.left=insert(node.left, l, h);
            }
            else{
                node.right=insert(node.right, l, h);
            }
            node.height=Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right))+1;
            node.max=findMax(node);
            int hd = heightDiff(node);
            if(hd<-1){
                int kk=heightDiff(node.right);
                if(kk>0){
                    node.right=rightRotate(node.right);
                    return leftRotate(node);
                }
                else{
                    return leftRotate(node);
                }
            }
            else if(hd>1){
                if(heightDiff(node.left)<0){
                    node.left = leftRotate(node.left);
                    return rightRotate(node);
                }
                else{
                    return rightRotate(node);
                } 
            }
            else;
        }
        return node;
    }
    private TreeNode<T> leftRotate(TreeNode<T> n){
        TreeNode<T> r =  n.right;
        n.right = r.left;
        r.left=n;
        n.height=Math.max(height(n.left), height(n.right))+1;
        r.height=Math.max(height(r.left), height(r.right))+1;
        n.max=findMax(n);
        r.max=findMax(r);
        return r;
    }
    private TreeNode<T> rightRotate(TreeNode<T> n){
        TreeNode<T> r =  n.left;
        n.left = r.right;
        r.right=n;
        n.height=Math.max(height(n.left), height(n.right))+1;
        r.height=Math.max(height(r.left), height(r.right))+1;
        n.max=findMax(n);
        r.max=findMax(r);
        return r;
    }
    private int heightDiff(TreeNode<T> a){
        if(a==null){
            return 0;
        }
        return height(a.left)-height(a.right);
    }
    private int height(TreeNode<T> a){
        if(a==null){
            return 0;
        }
        return a.height;
    }
    private T findMax(TreeNode<T> n){
        if(n.left==null && n.right==null){
            return n.max;
        }
        if(n.left==null){
            if(((Comparable)n.right.max).compareTo(n.max)>0){
                return n.right.max;
            }
            else{
                return n.max;
            }
        }
        if(n.right==null){
           if(((Comparable)n.left.max).compareTo(n.max)>0){
                return n.left.max;
            }
            else{
                return n.max;
            } 
        }
        Comparable c1 = (Comparable)n.left.max;
        Comparable c2 = (Comparable)n.right.max;
        Comparable c3 = (Comparable)n.max;
        T max=null;
        if(c1.compareTo(c2)<0){
            max=n.right.max;
        }
        else{
            max=n.left.max;
        }
        if(c3.compareTo((Comparable)max)>0){
            max=n.max;
        }
        return max;
    }


TreeNode intervalSearch(T t1){
        TreeNode<T> t = root;
        while(t!=null && !isInside(t, t1)){
            if(t.left!=null){
                    if(((Comparable)t.left.max).compareTo(t1)>0){
                    t=t.left;
                }
                else{
                    t=t.right;
                }
            }
            else{
                t=t.right;
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
    private boolean isInside(TreeNode<T> node, T t){
        Comparable cLow=(Comparable)node.low;
        Comparable cHigh=(Comparable)node.high;
        int i = cLow.compareTo(t);
        int j = cHigh.compareTo(t);
        if(i<=0 && j>=0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. An interesting implementation. Can you provide a main with a simple test case? Or if you prefer a junit test? Thank you.

Comment: For future readers: If I'm not mistaken all the n,max in findMax should be replaced with n.high. Otherwise you can get the wrong max when rotating (when the source of the current max is rotated above n)

Comment: How do I get all intervals that intersect with a given interval?